# Selenium Actions Sendkeys does not return a UnhandledAlertException if browser if configured with setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(ACCEPT_AND_NOTIFY);

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, alert

I have configured my Webbrowser with the options `options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(ACCEPT_AND_NOTIFY);`
but when I run
`WebElement.sendKeys(text);`
it doesn't return an UnhandledAlertException.

Using `driver().executeAsyncScript(SCRIPT)` works, but the sendKeys method does not return the wanted result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.